# How to increase height of tinymce Iframe?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, tinymce-4

On my page there are 3 tinymce editor are there in different tabs. I want to increase the iframe height of specific tinymce.

and these editor are in modal box. When I click button then it opens different tabs.

I have included my content_css in `tinymce.yml` file

```
mode: "exact"
selector: "textarea.tinymce"
theme: "modern"
#encoding : "xml"
convert_urls: false
content_css: "/assets/my_tinymce.css"
```

I have added my css in this `my_tinymce.css` but it was not working.

Also added my jquery code on the same page to change the height using jquery but did not get any success.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $("#iframe_id_of_selected_tinymce").css("height","300px");
});
```

please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got the solution, add following lines on your page. which will create specific class for specific text area.

```
<script>
    tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "specific_textareas",
        editor_selector : "my_tinymce",
        height : "300px"
    });
</script>
```

and add this `my_tinymce` class to textarea you want.

```
<textarea rows="10" name="textarea" id="textarea" cols="180" class="my_tinymce" aria-hidden="true"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
$("#iframe_id_of_selected_tinymce").height(500);
```

i think the problem with your jquery code is the semi colon in "300px;", you don't need that

Comment: Yes I have corrected my semicolon, also tried your solution but did not work.